# Bugsense not sending crash reports

Tags: android, bugsense

I have just implemented bugsense 3.2 library in my android application, prior to release for testing to client. My app is in testing stage. To test crash reports, i had deliberately put a crash code in my activity.

```
BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(MainActivity.this, "MY_KEY"); // MY_KEY is replaced with actual key
String a = null;
a.toString();
```

Application crashed as expected, but I havn't received any crash report on my registered email id. My question is, How long bugsense takes to report a crash? or is there anything I am doing wrong.

I have given required internet permission.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Please help, my client is loosing patience as he is experiencing some crash in the app which i am unable to find out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Kostas, the Android Developer of the plugin at BugSense.
First of all, please make sure your API key is correct. There is also a debug option you can use, you can enable it with BugSenseHandler.I_WANT_TO_DEBUG = true; just before the init. This will show you what goes wrong.

Comment: BugSenseHandler.I_WANT_TO_DEBUG = true;
BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(this, apiKey);

This doesn't work for me. Errors are reported but crashes are not, neither real-time nor insight wise.

Also debug mode throws nothing on the log. Tried with 'bug', 'sense' and any other filter combination of that.

Comment: I tried making the app crash with either an UnsuportedOperationException and with: int a = 34 / 0; both indeed made the app crash.

Comment: Hello! The default BugSense logcat tag is "BugSenseHandler" so please try again by enabling the debugging before you initialize the plugin and test the logcat output using the following command: adb logcat BugSenseHandler:* *:s

Answer (score 0):

> How long bugsense takes to report a crash?

I used bugsense in my project to send logcat on web panel of bugsense. It display the logcat immediately and make sure mobile is connected with internet.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    BugSenseHandler.initAndStartSession(Context, APIKEY);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //rest of your code here
}
```

and Please check the API Key you are using here is right.

You have multiple alternative to get logcat.

For getting error trace you can use [Application Crash Report for Android](http://code.google.com/p/acra/).

or

I have one project on github that send the error trace on developer email account.

Download from [here](https://github.com/ajaysaini-sgvu/CrashReport).